# Formal Power Series for Recursion where Successor is Linear Combination of all Predecessors

Tags: combinatorics, recursion, fibonacci-numbers, catalan-numbers, formal-power-series

I am trying to solve a recursion of the form
\begin{equation*}a_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} k_{j,n} \cdot a_j + d_n \end{equation*} where $k_{j,n}$ and $d_n$ are constants depending on $j,n$ and $n$, respectively.  Does a closed form to express $a_n$ explicitly exist? Or does anyone have similar examples?

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Every sequence is of this form, so maybe you can be more explicit about what you would consider an acceptable answer?  You have put some tags like catalan-numbers and fibonacci-numbers on the post; this suggests that your real question is not exactly what you have written.

Comment: I meant that the coefficients before $a_j$ really are always different for any $j$ and also depend on $n$ (but there is an explicit formula to calculate $k_{j,n}$) This makes it difficult for me to proceed in a similar way as with proofing an explicit expression for the Catalan/fibonacci numbers. Actually, if anyone had encountered a similar problem, a solution to this might give me some ideas for my particular recursion (which is very ugly, unfortunately)

Comment: For every sequence $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$, there are (many) choices of $(k_{j, n})$ and $(d_n)$ such that your sequence satisfies this recurrence.  So right now your question is "does every sequence have a closed form?" I think you should add to the question the particular recursion you are interested in, not just some much more general thing of which your recursion is a special case.

Comment: @Antigone $n=1$ gives you $a_1 = d_1$, then if you  write the relations for $2,3,\ldots,n$ you get a linear system of $n-1$ equations with $n-1$ unknowns $a_2, a_3,\ldots,a_n$. You can solve it like you would solve any linear system, and you can get an explicit expression for $a_n$ in terms of $k_{i,j}$ and $d_j$ using Cramer's rule, for example, but the determinants will quickly become tedious to calculate. You might get better help if you posted the actual problem you are trying to solve.